# Como puedo resolver esto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend

Vengo aquí porque realmente ya aplique todo lo básico que se sobre javascript, ya que estoy aprendiendo. Hace poco encontré un portal llamado CodeWars, en dicho portal uno va completando ejercicios y avanzando de nivel y un sin fin de cosas. Bueno el hecho es que me asignaron resolver este ejercicio:

//Complete el método/función para que convierta las palabras delimitadas por guiones/guiones bajos a mayúsculas y minúsculas.
//La primera palabra dentro de la salida debe estar en mayúsculas solo si la palabra original estaba en mayúsculas
//(conocido como Upper Camel Case, también conocido como Pascal case).
//Ejemplo:

```
//"the-stealth-warrior" gets converted to "theStealthWarrior"

//"The_Stealth_Warrior" gets converted to "TheStealthWarrior"
```

Comencé aplicando lo poco que se porque como comente, estoy aprendiendo este hermoso lenguaje.

Aquí el código:

```js
let var1 = "the-stealth-warrior"; //Cree la variable
let var2 = var1.split("-"); //Use el metodo split() con "-" para que me devolviera un array sin guion -

let var3 = new String(var2); //Converti el array a string con el constructor New String()

let regExp = ","; //Cree una expresion regular
let var4 = var3.replace(regExp, ""); //Hice que el resultado de replace() se guardara en la variable var4
console.log(var4); //Imprime thestealth,warrior si se fijan aun tiene una ,

let otherVar = var4.replace(/,/g, ""); //Use replace() nuevamente para quitar la ultima ,
console.log(otherVar); //thestealthwarrior

//Esta es la funcion que deberia devolver: TheStealthWarrior
function camelCase(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, (word, index) => {
      return index === 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
    })
    .replace(/\s+/g, "");
}
console.log(camelCase(otherVar)); //Devuelve: thestealthwarrior

/*
Necesito que me ayuden a resolverlo y de paso me expliquen, los metodos que uticen para completarlo, asi los pongo en practica.
*/
```

Necesito que me ayuden a resolverlo y de paso me expliquen, los métodos que utilicen para completarlo, así los pongo en practica.

Comment: Hola Light, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, existe muchas formas de hacer esto, te recomiendo cambies tu pregunta de lo contrario puede ser cerrada PD. lo primero que puedes hacer es un split por guion luego con un map colocar la primera letra mayuscula y por ultimo un join("") `var1.split("-")
       .map(palabra => palabra[0]
       .toUpperCase().concat(palabra.slice(1)))
       .join('');`

Answer (score 1):

Light-san te propongo mi solución. la ventaja es que funciona incluso cuando la separación es mixta, es decir, si utiliza una combinación de `-` y `_`.

```js
function transformar(input){
    let res = "" //En res almacenamos el resultado

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){ //Recorremos la entrada caracter por caracter
        if (input[i] === '-' || input[i] === '_'){ //Si el caracter es - o _
            res += input[i+1].toUpperCase() //Agregamos la siguiente letra, convertida a mayúscula, a res
            i++ //Nos salteamos 1 caracter
        } else { //Si es cualquier otro caracter
            res += input[i] //Lo agregamos a res
        }
    }   
    return res
}

console.log(transformar('separados-por-guiones'))
console.log(transformar('separados_Por_Guiones_Bajos'))
console.log(transformar('Con_Separacion-mixta'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Es posible utilizar expresiones regulares (`regex`) para revisar si los caracteres son `-` o `_`

```js
function camelCase(str) {
    // Creamos una variable para identificar si tenemos que utilizar mayúscula o no
    let upper = false;
    // String con la primera letra para conservar si es mayúscula o minúscula
    let newStr = str[0];
    // Recorremos el resto del string
    for (let i = 1, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Si el caracter en la posición "i" es "-" o "_" lo brincamos con "continue"
        if (str[i].match(/(-|_)/)) {
            upper = true; // Hacemos upper true para que el siguiente caracter sea mayúscula
            continue;
        }
        // Concatenamos al nuevo string el caracter en la posición "i"
        // Usamos un operador ternario para evaluar si el caracter debe ir con mayúscula o minúscula
        // condición ? siVerdadero : siFalso; 
        newStr += upper ? str[i].toUpperCase() : str[i].toLowerCase(); // Operador ternario
        upper = false;
    }
    // Al final del for regresamos el nuevo string
    return newStr;
}

console.log(camelCase("the-stealth-warrior"));
console.log(camelCase("The-stealth-warrior"));
console.log(camelCase("the_stealth_warrior"));
console.log(camelCase("The_stealth_warrior"));
console.log(camelCase("the_stealth-warrior"));
console.log(camelCase("The_stealth-warrior"));
```

Salida:

```
theStealthWarrior
TheStealthWarrior
theStealthWarrior
TheStealthWarrior
theStealthWarrior
TheStealthWarrior
```

Comment: No es un poco excesivo usar regex en este caso?

Answer (score 0):

Con un array auxiliar para asi aprovechar  métodos disponibles.
Ubica la posición del carácter decide si el carácter siguiente
es mayúscula o minúscula guarda la posición de este para comparar
y así no agregar
una carácter adicional convirtiendo luego el array a una cadena

```js
const frase = "The_stealth_warrior";
const frase2 = "The_Stealth_Warrior";
const frase3 = "The-Stealth-warrior";


function convertir(frase) {
  let a;
  let arry = []
  for (let i in frase) {
    if (frase[i] === "_" || frase[i] === "-") {
      a = parseInt(i) + 1
      if (frase[a].toLowerCase() === frase[a]) {
        arry.push(frase[a].toUpperCase())

      } else {
        arry.push(frase[a])
      }

    } else {
      if (i != a) {
        arry.push(frase[i])
      }
    }

  }
  return arry.join('')
}
let uno = convertir(frase2);
console.log(frase2 + "-->", uno);
//The_Stealth_Warrior--> TheStealthWarrior



let dos = convertir(frase);
console.log(frase + "-->", dos);
// The_stealth_warrior--> TheStealthWarrior


let tres = convertir(frase3);
console.log(frase3, "--->", tres)
// The-Stealth-warrior ---> TheStealthWarrior
```

> Otra forma de acuerdo a tu código utilizando replace(). no resumo las
> expresiónes para facilitar tu lectura

```js
let frase1 = "the-stealth-Warrior";
let frase2 = "the-Stealth_warrior";
let frase3 = "the_Stealth-Warrior";

function camelCase(str) {
  // el primer replace agregara un S o una W
  // no resumo la exprecion para facilitar tu //lectura
  return str
    .replace(/[- _]/g, (word, index) => {
      if (index) {
        return str[index + 1].toUpperCase()
      }

    })
    // con el flag i no se repetiran caracteres s ni //w
    .replace(/sS/gi, 'S')
    .replace(/WW/gi, 'W')
}
console.log('the-stealth-Warrior:--->', camelCase(frase1));

console.log('the-Stealth_warrior:--->', camelCase(frase2));
console.log('the_Stealth-Warrior:--->', camelCase(frase3))
```

```
Resultado:
the-stealth-Warrior:---> theStealthWarrior
the-Stealth_warrior:---> theStealthWarrior
the_Stealth-Warrior:---> theStealthWarrior
```

Comment: Gracias a todos amigos todas sus opciones funcionaron sin problemas. Aunque no lo crean soy un chico con muchas ganas de aprender a programar, y con esa ayuda no saben lo mucho que me han ayudado e inspirado. Espero convertir en un buen desarrollador full stack, para igual que ustedes poder ayudar a mas personas, como ustedes lo hicieron conmigo. GRACIAS!!

Comment: Que bueno que te resultaron útiles todas las respuestas en el ejemplo que diste no Tenes necesidad de definir var3 con `console.log(var2.join(''));` evitas la comas. También a la función lo conveniente es pasarle la cadena original y usar replace para encontrar al - cuidando de como  comparas a index